# What is Oracle equivalent for Linked Server and can you join with SQL Server?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, linked-server

In SQL Server I can create a view that is a join between two tables that are in completely different servers using Linked Server. If I change one of the servers from SQL Server to be Oracle, can I still do the same?

I need the join table to be in Oracle

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

In Oracle, this is called *"Heterogeneous Connectivity"* [This Oracle admin manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28277/toc.htm) has details.

[This article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_heterogeneous_database_connections_sql_server.htm) walks through an example case of doing the above steps with details.

The basic outline is:

> 1. Install ODBC drivers on Oracle server
> 2. Configure ODBC to talk to the SQL Server DB (create a system DSN)
> 3. Test the ODBC
> 4. Configure Global_Names parameter to false.
> 5. Create initodbc.ora file to configure Heterogeneous services
> 6. Modify listener.ora to connect to both Oracle and ODBC drivers
> 7. Modify tnsNames.ora file
> 8. Reload the listener to see the above changes.
> 9. Create a DB Link from Oracle to the ODBC connection.
> 10. Test via SQL Select statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I created a database link so that I could connect to SQL Server from my Oracle database.

My existing environment:

- a Windows server running Oracle 12c with Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC component installed.  (To check, look on the Oracle DB server. If  `%ORACLE_HOME%\BIN\dg4odbc.exe` exists, Database Gateway is probably installed already.)  Oracle instance is operational and fully functional in our organization, so important `listener.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` files are configured correctly.  I ran `Select * from v$parameter where name = 'global_names'` and confirmed that the value was `false`.
- a separate Windows server running Microsoft SQL Server. This is what I wanted to connect to from my Oracle DB.  I had a SQL Server authentication login (username/password) configured for use when connecting from Oracle, and made sure it had the necessary access to the SQL Server databases I want to query.

### Steps

1. On Windows server hosting Oracle database, I opened up ODBC (64-bit) and created a System DSN pointing to my Microsoft SQL Server.  I tested it and connectivity was successful. (TIP: make sure to set the database you want to connect to as the default database in this DSN connection, as it <s>may</s> **will** be the only one you can access from your Oracle link, if you have multiple databases.)
2. I created a file called `init?????.ora` in the directory `%ORACLE_HOME%\hs\admin\`, where `?????` is the name of the System DSN I created in Step 1.  This file contains the following lines:

   ```
   HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO=<System DSN name>
   HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL=off
   ```
3. Edited my `listener.ora` file located at `%ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\ADMIN\`.  There were already a bunch of `SID_DESC` items nested within `(SID_LIST_LISTENER = (SID_LIST =`  ...   We need to add one (properly nested) for our ODBC System DSN:

   ```
   (SID_DESC =
     (PROGRAM = dg4odbc) 
     (ORACLE_HOME = <path to your ORACLE_HOME>)
     (SID_NAME = <System DSN name>)
   )
   ```
4. Created an entry in my `tnsnames.ora` file (located in same directory as `listener.ora`):

   ```
   <Whatever name we give this connection>=
     (DESCRIPTION=
       (ADDRESS=
         (PROTOCOL=TCP)
         (HOST=localhost)
         (PORT=1521)
       )
       (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=<System DSN name>))
         (HS=OK)
   )
   ```
5. In SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, I created a database link. This is where I entered the credentials needed to connect to the target SQL Server:

   ```
   CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK <Name of DB Link> 
    CONNECT TO "user" IDENTIFIED BY "password" 
    USING '<Name we gave the connection in tnsnames.ora>';
   ```
6. Opened an elevated command prompt and restarted the Oracle listener service by running `lsnrctl stop` and then `lsnrctl start`  (shouldn't affect connected users...)
7. Opened up SQL Developer and tested it out by running a query against the now linked SQL Server database (as limited by the access of the account used to access it).

   ```
    --Basic ODBC connectivity test:
    select * from dual@<Name we gave link in Step 5>

    SELECT * FROM SomeTable@<Name we gave link in Step 5>;

    SELECT * FROM <optional schema.>SomeTable@<Name we gave link in Step 5>;
   ```

Proper Oracle documentation can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OTGIS/configodbc.htm#OTGIS110).